# ArcGIS Pro Broken Conda Environment

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, conda

I recently tried to install geopandas and shapely into my ArcGIS Pro Python 3.7 environment, but instead of utilizing the package manager within Pro, I foolishly tried to `conda install` into the base environment using miniforge3 (for Windows 10). I then tried to fix a dependency issue by uninstalling and reinstalling geos, but now my ArcGIS base environment is hopelessly broken, as it cannot seem to access numpy, mkl, or gdal.

Somehow, the process of installing/reinstalling these packages caused Python to upgrade from 3.7.9 to 3.7.10, and now my attempts to `conda install --revision 0` are being met with a litany of PackagesNotFoundErrors. Pro tells me that my base environment is broken when I go to the package manager, but it won't allow me to make any modifications to the base environment.

Is there anything I can do short of a full reinstallation of Pro?

Comment: Sometimes the path of least resistance is to simply do a reinstallation.